# Postgres parameter replacement syntax error

Tags: postgresql

When using this standard SQL everything works fine (i.e. is replaced correctly):

```
begin transaction;
prepare testquery2 (varchar) AS SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE name=$1;
execute testquery2 ('Hotel');
end transaction;
```

But with this special Postgres SQL:

```
begin transaction;
prepare testquery1 (varchar) AS SELECT * FROM cache WHERE AGE(now() ,last_modified) > interval $1;
execute testquery1 ('5 minutes');
end transaction;
```

-> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"

Comment: As you are referring to "standard SQL". The interval syntax in standard SQL is `interval '5' minute`, but I think you still wouldn't be able to use `interval $1 minute` though. What you could do is: `interval '1' minute * $1` to be compliant with the SQL standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follow up replies here are correct, but I don't think any of the posts thoroughly resolves the poster's issue.

The underlying issue relates to the INTERVAL Date/Time Type, described here in the Postgres documentation:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

The proposed solution by the original poster fails because of this bit, pulled from the docs:

> When writing an interval constant with a fields specification, or when assigning a string to an interval column that was defined with a fields specification, the interpretation of unmarked quantities depends on the fields. For example INTERVAL '1' YEAR is read as 1 year, whereas INTERVAL '1' means 1 second. Also, field values "to the right" of the least significant field allowed by the fields specification are silently discarded. For example, writing INTERVAL '1 day 2:03:04' HOUR TO MINUTE results in dropping the seconds field, but not the day field.

As a result the original poster's solution cannot work, which is easily shown by just preparing and executing this simple test:

```
prepare testquery1 (varchar) AS SELECT interval '$1';
PREPARE
vkmlm=> execute testquery1 ('5 minutes');
 interval
----------
 00:00:01
(1 row)
```

A workaround that you could use would be to format your INTERVAL query along the following lines:

```
prepare testquery2 (text) as select (INTERVAL '$1' MINUTES);
PREPARE
vkmlm=> EXECUTE testquery2('5');
 interval
----------
  5 minutes
(1 row)
```

But this is less than ideal. Most of us want to be using a variable in combination with the keyword. Fortunately there is a very easy way to do this, and I believe this is what the poster was originally looking for:

```
vkmlm=> prepare testquery3 (varchar) AS SELECT $1::interval;
PREPARE
vkmlm=> execute testquery3 ('5 minutes');
 interval
----------
 00:05:00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution - use quoted:

```
 begin transaction;
 prepare testquery1 (varchar) AS SELECT * FROM cache WHERE AGE(now() ,last_modified) > interval '$1';
 execute testquery1 ('5 minutes');
 end transaction;
```

Seems like Postgres is somehow inconsistent here since not using standard SQL?

Comment: The `interval` syntax is only valid for literals; parameters are not literals. You'll have the same issue with `PREPARE selint(integer) AS SELECT INTEGER $1;` or similar. Parameters are substituted at bind time, after parsing. So you have to use a cast, or as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests for intervals, multiply by a constant.

Comment: Your solution as posted is incorrect. I hope you didn't put that into production...